# Using untyped F# quotations to copy an array without knowing the type

Tags: arrays, f#, quotations

I'm working on a small project to using quotations to clone trees of some basic record types and I have it working in most cases, the big problem I'm having is with arrays.

```
module FSharpType = 
    /// predicate for testing types to see if they are generic option types
    let IsOption (stype: System.Type) = stype.Name = "FSharpOption`1"
    /// predicate for testing types to see if they are generic F# lists
    let IsList (stype: System.Type) = stype.Name = "FSharpList`1"


module RecordCloning =
    let inline application prms expr = Expr.Application(expr, prms)
    let inline coerse typ expr = Expr.Coerce(expr, typ)

    let (|IsMapType|_|) (t: Type) = 
        if t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<Map<_,_>> then Some t
        else None    


    let rec copyThing (mtype: Type) : Expr = 
        match mtype with 
        | _ when FSharpType.IsRecord mtype -> genRecordCopier mtype
        | _ when FSharpType.IsUnion mtype  -> genUnionCopier mtype 
        | _ when mtype.IsValueType || mtype = typeof<String> -> <@@ id @@>
        | _ when mtype.IsArray -> genArrayCopier mtype
        | IsMapType t -> <@@ id @@>
        | _ when mtype = typeof<System.Object> -> <@@ id @@>
        | _ -> failwithf "Unexpected Type: %s" (mtype.ToString())

    and genRecordCopier (rtype: Type) : Expr =         
        let arg = Var("x", typeof<obj>, false)
        let argExpr = Expr.Var(arg)
        let useArg = Expr.Coerce(argExpr, rtype)
        let fields = FSharpType.GetRecordFields(rtype)
        let members = [ for field in fields -> genFieldCopy useArg field ]
        let newrec = Expr.Coerce(Expr.NewRecord(rtype, members),typeof<obj>)
        Expr.Lambda(arg, newrec)

    and genFieldCopy argExpr (field: PropertyInfo) : Expr = 
        let pval = Expr.PropertyGet(argExpr, field)
        let convfun = copyThing field.PropertyType           
        let applied = Expr.Application (convfun, Expr.Coerce(pval, typeof<obj>))
        Expr.Coerce(applied, field.PropertyType)

    and castToType (atype : Type) : Expr = 
        let arg = Var("x", typeof<obj>, false)
        let argExpr = Expr.Var(arg)        
        Expr.Lambda(arg, Expr.Coerce(argExpr, atype))

    and coerseLambda (outterType: Type) (lambda: Expr) : Expr =
        let arg = Var("x", outterType, false)
        let argExpr = Expr.Var(arg)        

        let wrappedLambda = 
            lambda 
            |> application (argExpr |> coerse typeof<obj>)
            |> coerse outterType

        Expr.Lambda(arg, wrappedLambda)


    and genArrayCopier (atype : Type) : Expr = 
        let etype = atype.GetElementType()        
        let copyfun = copyThing etype

        let arg = Var("arr", typeof<obj>, false)
        let argExpr = Expr.Var(arg) |> coerse atype
        let wrappedLambda = coerseLambda etype copyfun
        let func =  <@@ Array.map (%%wrappedLambda) (%%argExpr) @@>
        Expr.Lambda(arg, func)


    and genOptionCopier (otype: Type) : Expr = 
        let etype = otype.GetGenericArguments().[0]
        let copyfun = copyThing etype
        <@@ fun (inobj: obj) -> 
                let x = inobj :?> Option<'t>
                match x with
                | Some v -> Some <| (%%copyfun) (box v)
                | None -> None
                |> box
         @@>

    and genUnionCopier (utype: Type) : Expr = 
        let cases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases utype
        // if - union case - then - copy each field into new case - else - next case

        let arg = Var("x", typeof<obj>, false)
        let argExpr = Expr.Var(arg)
        let useArg = Expr.Coerce(argExpr, utype)

        let genCaseTest case = Expr.UnionCaseTest (useArg, case)

        let makeCopyCtor (ci: UnionCaseInfo) = 
            let copiedMembers = [ for field in ci.GetFields() -> genFieldCopy useArg field ]
            Expr.Coerce(Expr.NewUnionCase(ci, copiedMembers), typeof<obj>)

        let genIf ifCase thenCase elseCase = Expr.IfThenElse(ifCase, thenCase, elseCase)

        let nestedIfs = 
            cases
            |> Array.map (fun case -> genIf (genCaseTest case) (makeCopyCtor case))
            |> Array.foldBack (fun iff st -> iff st) <| <@@ failwith "Unexpected Case Condition" @@>

        let newunion = Expr.Coerce(nestedIfs,typeof<obj>)
        Expr.Lambda(arg, newunion)

    let wrapInType<'I,'O> (lambdaExpr: Expr) : Expr<'I -> 'O> =
       <@ fun (v : 'I) -> (%%lambdaExpr : obj -> obj) (box v) :?> 'O @>

    let toLinq<'I,'O> (expr: Expr<'I -> 'O>) =
        let linq = Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression expr
        let call = linq :?> MethodCallExpression
        let lambda  = call.Arguments.[0] :?> LambdaExpression
        Expression.Lambda<Func<'I,'O>>(lambda.Body, lambda.Parameters)

    let genrateRecordDeepCopyFunction<'T> () : ('T -> 'T) = 
        let expr = genRecordCopier typeof<'T> 
        let castExpr : Expr<obj -> obj> = expr |> Expr.Cast
        let compiledExpr = (castExpr |> toLinq).Compile()
        fun (v : 'T) -> compiledExpr.Invoke(box v) :?> 'T
```

I've tried several approaches, but I always get complaints about wanting (string -> string) but getting (obj -> obj) or wanting (object [] -> object []) but getting (string [] -> string []).  Any ideas?

---

Here's a simple test case.

```
type SimpleArrayRecord = { Names: string array }

[<Fact>]
let ``record cloning should be able to clone a record with a simple array`` () =
    let sr = { Names = [|"Rick"; "David"; "Mark"; "Paul"; "Pete"|] }
    let func = RecordCloning.genrateRecordDeepCopyFunction<SimpleArrayRecord>()
    let res = func sr
    Assert.Equal(sr, res)
```

---

Here's the method that has gotten me the furthest.  The issue seems to be that I can't get it to make the array typed, and so it always fails on the cast when trying to build the record.  Adding a cast in the comprehension doesn't help.

```
and genArrayCopier (atype : Type) : Expr = 
    let etype = atype.GetElementType()        
    let copyfun = copyThing etype

    let arg = Var("arr", typeof<obj>, false)
    let argExpr = Expr.Var(arg) |> coerse atype

    <@@ fun (inobj: obj) -> 
            let arr = inobj :?> obj[] in 
                   [| for i = 0 to arr.Length - 1 do yield (%%copyfun) (Array.get arr i) |] |> box @@>
```

Toyvo's solution below works for the example above but not for arrays of records:

```
type SimpleRecord = { Name: string; Age: int }
type LotsOfRecords = { People: SimpleRecord [] }

[<Fact>]
let ``record cloning should be able to clone a record with an array of records`` () =
    let sr = { People = [|{Name = "Rick"; Age = 33 }; { Name = "Paul"; Age = 55 }|] }
    let func = RecordCloning.genrateRecordDeepCopyFunction<LotsOfRecords>()
    let res = func sr
    Assert.Equal(sr, res)
```

For those who come later, here's the working code.  I removed Option and haven't taken the time to clean it up but it's otherwise pretty decent.

```
let inline application prms expr = Expr.Application(expr, prms)
let inline coerse typ expr = Expr.Coerce(expr, typ)
let inline newrec typ args = Expr.NewRecord(typ, args)

let (|IsMapType|_|) (t: Type) = 
    if t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<Map<_,_>> then Some t
    else None    

let rec copyThing (mtype: Type) : Expr = 
    match mtype with 
    | _ when FSharpType.IsRecord mtype -> genRecordCopier mtype
    | _ when FSharpType.IsUnion mtype  -> genUnionCopier mtype 
    | _ when mtype.IsValueType || mtype = typeof<String> -> getIdFunc mtype
    | _ when mtype.IsArray -> genArrayCopier mtype
    | IsMapType t -> getIdFunc mtype
    | _ when mtype = typeof<System.Object> -> getIdFunc mtype
    | _ -> failwithf "Unexpected Type: %s" (mtype.ToString())

and X<'T> : 'T = Unchecked.defaultof<'T>

and getMethod = 
    function
    | Patterns.Call (_, m, _) when m.IsGenericMethod -> m.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
    | Patterns.Call (_, m, _) -> m
    | _ -> failwith "Incorrect getMethod Pattern"

and getIdFunc itype =
    let arg = Var("x", itype, false)
    let argExpr = Expr.Var(arg)        
    let func = 
        let m = (getMethod <@ id X @>).MakeGenericMethod([|itype|])
        Expr.Call(m, [argExpr])
    Expr.Lambda(arg, func)

and genRecordCopier (rtype: Type) : Expr =         
    let arg = Var("x", rtype, false)
    let argExpr = Expr.Var(arg) //|> coerse rtype
    let newrec =            
        FSharpType.GetRecordFields(rtype) |> Array.toList
        |> List.map (fun field -> genFieldCopy argExpr field)
        |> newrec rtype
    Expr.Lambda(arg, newrec)

and genFieldCopy argExpr (field: PropertyInfo) : Expr = 
    let pval = Expr.PropertyGet(argExpr, field) 
    copyThing field.PropertyType |> application pval

and genArrayCopier (atype : Type) : Expr = 
    let etype = atype.GetElementType()        
    let copyfun = copyThing etype

    let arg = Var("arr", atype, false)
    let argExpr = Expr.Var(arg)

    let func =
        let m = (getMethod <@ Array.map X X @>).MakeGenericMethod([|etype; etype|])
        Expr.Call(m, [copyfun; argExpr])

    Expr.Lambda(arg, func)

and genUnionCopier (utype: Type) : Expr = 
    let cases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases utype
    // if - union case - then - copy each field into new case - else - next case

    let arg = Var("x", utype, false)
    let useArg = Expr.Var(arg)

    let genCaseTest case = Expr.UnionCaseTest (useArg, case)

    let makeCopyCtor (ci: UnionCaseInfo) = 
        let copiedMembers = [ for field in ci.GetFields() -> genFieldCopy useArg field ]
        Expr.NewUnionCase(ci, copiedMembers)

    let genIf ifCase thenCase elseCase = Expr.IfThenElse(ifCase, thenCase, elseCase)

    let typedFail (str: string) =
        let m = (getMethod <@ failwith str @>).MakeGenericMethod([|utype|])
        Expr.Call(m, [ <@ str @> ])

    let nestedIfs = 
        cases
        |> Array.map (fun case -> genIf (genCaseTest case) (makeCopyCtor case))
        |> Array.foldBack (fun iff st -> iff st) <| (typedFail "Unexpected Case in Union")

    Expr.Lambda(arg, nestedIfs)
```

Now it actually works with unions as well.  Cheers!

Comment: Could you provide an actual repro?  What's not working?

Comment: Added a simple test case there, but it should also be able to handle arrays of records. Figure arrays of strings are a good first step.

Comment: Please don't use monikers like "EDIT" in your posts.  Every post on Stack Overflow has a detailed, time-stamped edit history that anyone can view.  The edit history for this post can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24001730/revisions).

Comment: Why not use a canned data-generic programming solution such as "Infers"  lib? Besides that, the probl. is simply not using generics correctly, let me try to fix quickly.

Comment: Well, the goal is eventually to have something that will clone a given type tree and update it with new values along the way where necessary with path-value pairs.  Also, I haven't heard of the infers lib, have a link?

Comment: https://github.com/VesaKarvonen/Infers - I think this falls into scope where Infers could really help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do this, make sure you understand generics and how to generate them. You are in LISP land, type system won't help you, since it cannot reason about itself - you are manipulating F# terms with F#.

```
and getMethod q =
    match q with
    | Patterns.Call (_, m, _) ->
        if m.IsGenericMethod then
            m.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
        else
            m
    | _ -> failwith "getMethod"

and X<'T> : 'T =
    Unchecked.defaultof<'T>

and genArrayCopier (atype : Type) : Expr = 
    let etype = atype.GetElementType()        
    let copyfun = copyThing etype

    let arg = Var("arr", typeof<obj>, false)
    let argExpr = Expr.Var(arg) |> coerse atype
    let wrappedLambda = coerseLambda etype copyfun
    let func =
        let m = getMethod <@ Array.map X X @> // obtained (forall 'X 'Y, 'X[] -> 'Y[])
        let m = m.MakeGenericMethod([| etype; etype |]) // specialized to 'E[] -> 'E[]
        Expr.Call(m, [wrappedLambda; argExpr]) // now this type-checks
    Expr.Lambda(arg, func)
```

Comment: Ahh neat, I really like that getMethod pattern.

Comment: But it still fails when the record contains an array of records, I'll need to play a bit more to see where the issue is.

Comment: With that hint I went back and striped out all of the obj casts and it seems to be working much better now. Thanks!